# Bundle install error on remote server after capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

Here is the error from bundle install after capistrano deployment rails 3.1 app:

```
dtt@ubuntu:/$ cd /vol/www/emclab
dtt@ubuntu:/vol/www/emclab$ /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems
/home/dtt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /home/dtt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /home/dtt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
        from /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

Here is the output with gem list under /current subdir:

```
dtt@ubuntu:/vol/www/emclab/current$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.1)
actionpack (3.1.1)
activerecord (3.1.1)
activeresource (3.1.1)
activesupport (3.1.1)
arel (2.2.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
json (1.6.1)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
minitest (1.6.0)
multi_json (1.0.3)
passenger (3.0.9)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.3.5)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
railties (3.1.1)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.11, 2.5.8)
sprockets (2.0.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.30)
```

Here is the error for gem install bundler:

```
root@ubuntu:/vol/www/emclab/current# gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Any thoughts about how to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: `Could not find bundler` -- The bundler gem is not installed.

Comment: you meant bundler is not installed under /vol/www/emclab?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have `Bundler` installed. SSH to the remote machine and `sudo gem install bundler` first. Then the deployment should work.

Don't forget to ommit the `sudo` if you're using RVM, which means only `gem install bundler`.

Comment: gem install bundler under /vol/www/myapp/current?

Comment: yes, rvm installed on the server. Why to ommit sudo with rvm? I noticed that I could not use sudo for passenger-install-nginx-module but don't know why.

Comment: @user938363 installing passenger is something different. But using sudo with `rvm` generally causes a lot of problems and is considered a bad practice unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: what to do if su user privilege is needed to execute a command?

Comment: @user938363 if you need sudo privileges and you don't have them, there's not really much you can do. They won't let you do this on a shared hosting, and if it's your own VPS/server, then you should have an access to a root account.

Comment: dtt@ubuntu:/vol/www/emclab/current$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.